# how to loop through listagg

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Can you please help me with the bestway to solve below problem?

Problem: I have an oracle apex page which has a report with columns as department names and employee names along with check boxes. Upon selecting the one or more checkboxes and clicking on submit button following should happen.

1. the pl/sql code should fetch the department names of all the selected rows from emp table.
2. Next it should fetch employess names under each department for the selected checkboxes.

What is the bestway to accomplish this?

Below is my code.

```
    FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.count
    LOOP
    IF APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i) IS NOT NULL THEN
      select listagg(dept_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
      TESTSET_PATH) into str_dept_names from emptable
      WHERE 
      emptable._ID=APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i) group by dept_name;
     END IF;   
    END LOOP;


    FOR REC IN str_dept_names
    LOOP
      FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.count
       LOOP
       IF APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i) IS NOT NULL THEN
          select  listagg(ename,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
          dept_name) into str_enums from 
          emptable where dept_name LIKE 
          (rec.str_dept_names) and 
          emptable .ID 
         =APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i);

        myclob:=-myclob||'java -jar test.jar - 
        dept'||rec.str_dept_names||str_testnums;

        END IF;
     END LOOP;
     END LOOP;
```

My output in myclob should be: deptA,emp1,emp2

Answer (score 0):

The `apex_string` package, added in Apex 5, work with nested tables, which work very well with SQL. The downside is that you have to do a conversion. So I usually do something like this, to avoid loops:

```
if apex_application.g_f01.count > 0 then
    l_dept_ids := apex_string.split( apex_util.table_to_string( 
        apex_application.g_f01 ), ':' );

    select listagg(dept_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
           TESTSET_PATH) into str_dept_names 
      from emptable
     WHERE emptable._ID MEMBER OF l_dept_ids
end if;
```

I'm not sure I understand your second query enough. You're using a `LIKE` clause, but that seems very odd. Is `id` not a primary key?